# How to bind attributes values in MAUI component

Tags: maui

I'm trying to make a windows-like navigation item.
[image]

This is the implementation:

```html
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NavItem.NavItem"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavItem"
         x:DataType="local:NavItem">
<Frame HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="6" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" BorderColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" Padding="10">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="LblText" Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="{StaticResource White}" />
        <Label Text=">" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="{StaticResource White}" FontSize="16" />
    </Grid>
</Frame>
</ContentView>
```

```
public partial class NavItem : ContentView
{
    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set { text = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public NavItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(PageName);
    }
}
```

```html
<VerticalStackLayout>
  <local:NavItem Text="Page 1" PageName="Page1" />
  <local:NavItem Text="Page 2" PageName="Page2" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The navigation is ok but the binding fails to set Text property of label LblText.
So this is the rendering:
[image]

**EDIT**: I also tried with a bindable attribute, same result

```
public string Text
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(NavItem), "", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to set the binding context to itself:

```
public NavItem()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I have to wait 48h, I'll mark it tomorrow.